# How to write java method with return value

Tags: java

Sometimes I am not sure which variant I should use. I mean is the second method better thant the first? The first I think it needs more storage because I am storing one more variable. For clean code reason which would you prefer and why? Is my reasonable right or wrong?

```
public double area(){
    double area = 2 * radius * radius;
    return area;
}

public double area(){
    return 2 * radius * radius;
}
```

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but if you don't use the `area` variable (other than in the return statement), I'd say you don't need it.

Comment: The second approach is generally preferred. And static code analysis will usually tell you to use it.

Comment: The compiler will notice that the `area` variable is not used otherwise, so the two snippets produce the same bytecode. So this is about readability, the second one is shorter, elegant and precise. And most developers that read the first snippet will think "why did he/she use a variable?"

Comment: However, there are certain debugging environments in which you will not be able to see the value before you exit the method, unless you put it in a variable.

Comment: @f1sh The two snippets don't produce the same bytecode - the first version has an extra `dstore_1` and `dload_1` before the `dreturn`. However, the JIT should optimize that out at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From JVM standpoint both versions of code compile to the same bytecode (after optimization). So, 2 reasons I would prefer the first version:

1. Obviously easier to read
2. When debugging, you can stop at line `return area;` and check the value before getting out of the method. In the second version, you can not check the returned value before returning from the method

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash if you mean in the line "return 2 * radius * radius;" to inspect the value of the radius, yes, and you can inspect the entire expression, but it is not convenient.

Answer (score 1):

This might be bordering to opinion based answering...

From the resulting machine code, both variants are the same (at least after the JVM had a go in optimizing them). So the only difference here ist human readability.

Modern style guides and tools favor the second variant because it's less to read and clear enough. Modern (static code analysis) tools and IDEs (using these tools) would mark the first one as a "dead store" (in case of for example sonar) or "redundant" (in case of for example intelliJ IDE) that should be avoided.

Comment: A dead store means the variable is written to and then the value is never used; that's not the case here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_store

Comment: dead store? why? the value will be used everytime when I call the method? I don't get it.